# Programmatically add buttons to a UWP app

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Suppose my app has one button that adds another button.
If I press it, another button should appear right next to the first button.
Also, the new button should become the "add a new button"-button.

How do I do this?

My approach was creating a RelativePanel, because in the Editor, you can say "Place this left of that". 
However, it can't find a way to do that in C# code.

Comment: You can set the alignment in C# with the RelativePanel class for example RelativePanel.SetLeftOf(buttonA, buttonB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow [ctron's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42306705/programmatically-add-buttons-to-a-uwp-app#comment71769668_42306705) and do it via setting attached property value in the code. The sample can look like this - XAML:

```xml
<RelativePanel x:Name="myPanel" Margin="100">
    <Button Content="StartBtn" Click="Button_Click"/>
</RelativePanel>
```

and in the code behind:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button newButton = new Button { Content = "CreatedBtn" };
    newButton.Click += Button_Click;
    RelativePanel.SetLeftOf(newButton,sender);
    myPanel.Children.Add(newButton);
}
```

This will work fine, however if you click double times one button, the second new created one will overlap the one created from the first click. If it's not a desired behavior, you will have to do it other way, in that case you need a list of buttons. I've used horizontal *ListView* for that:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="myList">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding}" Click="ListButton_Click"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <x:String>StartBtn</x:String>
</ListView>
```

```cs
private void ListButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = myList.Items.IndexOf((e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext);
    myList.Items.Insert(index, $"Btn {myList.Items.Count}");
}
```

This need some more styling, but should show the basic idea.

Comment: Now, how do I specify the behaviour of the freshly generated buttons? I don't want them to add other buttons, they should do something else.

Comment: @DanielKrenn There are couple of ways to do that, very easy with the relative option, where you can just create new eventhandler for each created button. With list method you can define class for your item, put suitable delegate there or use command pattern, then upon item creation define what it should do. Try it yourself, if you don't success, post another question on SO with repro code and description what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi! Would you mind to provide sample where we can use two or more buttones in ListView item, please?

Comment: @AcademyofProgrammer You mean putting two buttons in StackPanel in item's Datatemplate?